# Redux with firebase autentication

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add authentication to my react using redux with redux tool kit
this is what I currently have
My sign in function to create createAsyncThunk

```
 export const signin = createAsyncThunk(
  'authentication/signin',
  async (signinCredentials: userData, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const { email, password } = signinCredentials;
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in
        const user = userCredential.user;
        return user;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        return rejectWithValue(errorMessage);
      });
  }
);
```

I have an interface for userState which looks like this

```
  export interface userState {
  user: object | null;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
  isAuth: boolean;
  message: string;
}
```

And this is the initial state

```
 const initialState: userState = {
  user: null,
  status: 'idle',
  isAuth: false,
  message: '',
};
```

My auth slice is this
The problem is when even i try to access action.payload. I have marked the areas with the errors from typescript

```
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signin.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
        state.isAuth = false;
      })
      .addCase(signin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.isAuth = true;
        state.user = action.payload; type void is not assignable to type 'object' | null
      })
      .addCase(signin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.isAuth = false;
        state.message = action.payload; type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'
      })     
  },
});
```

I have been trying to fix these issues for a while, but can't figure out what is happening. I have tried to leave as much information as possible, but if you need more. Please, let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk)

We should provide correct types of generic argument for `createAsyncThunk`  with type declarations for some or all of these fields:

```
type AsyncThunkConfig = {
  /** return type for `thunkApi.getState` */
  state?: unknown
  /** type for `thunkApi.dispatch` */
  dispatch?: Dispatch
  /** type of the `extra` argument for the thunk middleware, which will be passed in as `thunkApi.extra` */
  extra?: unknown
  /** type to be passed into `rejectWithValue`'s first argument that will end up on `rejectedAction.payload` */
  rejectValue?: unknown
  /** return type of the `serializeError` option callback */
  serializedErrorType?: unknown
  /** type to be returned from the `getPendingMeta` option callback & merged into `pendingAction.meta` */
  pendingMeta?: unknown
  /** type to be passed into the second argument of `fulfillWithValue` to finally be merged into `fulfilledAction.meta` */
  fulfilledMeta?: unknown
  /** type to be passed into the second argument of `rejectWithValue` to finally be merged into `rejectedAction.meta` */
  rejectedMeta?: unknown
}
```

So that the `action.payload` type in case reducer will be inferred correctly.

E.g.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

interface userData {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export const signin = createAsyncThunk<{ email: string }, userData, { rejectValue: string }>(
  'authentication/signin',
  async (signinCredentials: userData, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const { email, password } = signinCredentials;
    try {
      throw new Error('password incorrect');
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  },
);

export interface userState {
  user: object | null;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
  isAuth: boolean;
  message: string;
}
const initialState: userState = {
  user: null,
  status: 'idle',
  isAuth: false,
  message: '',
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'authentication',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signin.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
        state.isAuth = false;
      })
      .addCase(signin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.isAuth = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(signin.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.isAuth = false;
        if (action.payload) {
          state.message = action.payload;
        }
      });
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it